# java HttpClient Methods (LOAD, Confirm)

Tags: java, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String URL = ("http://www.alfa");
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
**i want to load the card with "LOAD" method and use "CONFIRM" method** 
*can someone suggest me how to write those methods or should i use only httpget and post methods*

Comment: It sounds as if you're referring to API level methods (eg, the API exposes functions called "load" and "confirm"). These are different than HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure a LOAD method exists, according to the RFC: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Does the API you're requesting access to specifically state "LOAD" instead of "GET" must be used?